# Upload screenshots by Ctrl+V

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

As I know it is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174068/upload-file-to-html5-page-using-keyboard-shortcuts) [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582685/file-upload-via-local-file-path) to upload the files by hooking `paste` event by javascript. 
But I have found such thing on [trello.com](http://trello.com)
How to reproduce:

**Only on windows and with google chrome** I can'not reproduce it on linux ff or chrome

1. Create a new card
2. Click on it -> it's form appeared
3. Click on comment text area
4. Make screenshot by <kbd>PrnScr</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> -> upload process started (green
   progress bar in right top corner)

So how do they implemented it?

Comment: without checking, maybe they hooked to the keystrokes rather than the paste event?  Curious if it works on Mac with Command-V

Comment: Hmm.. how it can be checked?

Comment: [imgur](http://imgur.com) can upload from a paste too

Comment: from my quick research it looks like java is handling paste uploads..I just briefly searched though so I may be wrong on this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage image pasting from clipboard in html5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219197/how-to-manage-image-pasting-from-clipboard-in-html5) - the functionality required is part of the clipboard API

Comment: @Bojangles imgur handles only web links in clipboard not local files but thanks.

Comment: Oops, so it does - sorry

Comment: Point of interest - StackOverflow also has clipboard image paste functionality. Just click the Image button 1st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Trello, they use an event handler registered on the paste event and basically accessing `event.clipboardData.items`.

The javascript code ([here](https://d2k1ftgv7pobq7.cloudfront.net/js/b1f84ab220b19d89075e817753092633/all.js)) is minified, hence not particularly easy to read, but it basically boils down to applying the trick found in that other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c)

Extract of the paste handler:

```
        c.prototype.paste = function (b) {
            var c, f, e, g, h, k, m, l;
            e = null;
            h = this.handlers;
            for (g in h)
                if (c = h[g], null != c.paste) {
                    e = c.paste;
                    break
                }
            if (null != e && (f = null != (k = null != (m = b.originalEvent) ? null != (l = m.clipboardData) ? l.items : void 0 : void 0) ? k : [], b = function (b) {
                return _.detect(f, function (c) {
                    return c.type === b
                })
            }, !b("text/plain") && (b = b("image/png"), null != b && (b = b.getAsFile(), null != b)))) return j.validFileSize(b) ? (n("Keyboard Shortcuts", "Paste - Upload Image From Clipboard"), e(b)) : P.show("File size exceeds 10mb limit",
                "error", "upload", 5E3)
        };
```