# how to screen capture a part of webpage then pass it to server with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My recent project need screen capture a part of webpage then pass it to server.I actually could use and find some screen capture tool to get a picture and save it in my computer, then use a form to upload the picture. But what I really want is simplify this process just like I take a screen capture and then press ctrl-v(something like that) to upload a picture.

could anyone give me some suggestion? I really hope I just make my problem clear and Thank you!

Comment: You cannot do this with Javascript. (Think about the implications if you could....webpages could start snapping screenshots of your computer and uploading to their servers.)

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible through javascript.
One thing you can do is search for screen capture tools which stores the link of the captured image(local directory).
So that you can upload the image to server by pasting the url link in the form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17163646/139300